std::variant::operator< unexpected call to implicit bool conversion. Varies between standards
I'm seeing some unexpected behavior when using the std::variant::operator<. In the situation where the type has an implicit bool conversion operator and its less operator is not a member function (in C++20 with mscv 19.38 compiler).
#include <variant>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;

#ifndef DROP_CAST_OP
    constexpr operator bool() const { return x || y; }
#endif

#ifdef USE_SPACESHIP
    constexpr auto operator<=>(const Foo&) const noexcept = default;
#else
    friend constexpr bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) noexcept
    {
        return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
    }
#endif
};

using TestVariant = std::variant<Foo, int>;

constexpr Foo fooA { 0, 1 };
constexpr Foo fooB { 1, 0 };
constexpr std::variant<Foo, int> varA = fooA;
constexpr std::variant<Foo, int> varB = fooB;

static_assert(fooA < fooB);
static_assert(varA < varB);

https://godbolt.org/z/1zfq5dq1r
Note that assertion starts to pass when one of the following conditions is met:

use C++17 instead C++20
use three-way comparison operator instead free function less operator
not defining implicit conversion to bool operator
marking conversion bool operator as explicit

All compilers have the same behavior.

It is recommended to use explicit operator bool, does it solve the problem?

Why do you have operator bool, instead of explicit operator bool?

So making it explicit operator bool does fix it. This object is tremendously old which is why it wasn't specified before.

Got ultimate constexpr repro for all major compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/34fsqY5dn

@MarekR nice thanks for digging into this so much

Re: "bool cast operator" -- it's a conversion operator; a cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78346768/11910702

Heh, I knew exactly what this code would be when I read the title. I can't find a great dupe target so I'll try to make this the canonical answer.
C++17
In C++17, std::variant (like a bunch of other class templates in the standard library, std::pair, std::tuple, and std::optional among them) define < in terms of deferring to the underlying types' <. The only operation invoked on the underlying type was T.
Specifically, what operator< would do on two objects of type variant<T, U> (assuming < was defined for both T and U) is first compare the indices and if those were the same, compare the values. Something like this:
bool operator<(variant<T, U> const& lhs, variant<T, U> const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.index() != rhs.index()) {
        return lhs.index() < rhs.index();
    }
   
    // not this specifically, but this conceptually
    return std::get<lhs.index()>(lhs) < std::get<rhs.index()>(rhs);
}

C++20
C++20 introduced <=>, which is generally a much better way of dealing with ordering and came with a lot of conveniences to make writing comparisons (equality and ordering) easier. But it also came with the problem that no code before C++20 had <=> available. So we can't wholesale just change std::variant's comparison to use <=> because no existing code uses <=>.
Instead, the library preferentially uses <=> but falls back to < if <=> isn't available. It does so with a specification-only object called synth-three-way, specified in [expos.only.entity]:
  constexpr auto synth-three-way =                 // exposition only
    []<class T, class U>(const T& t, const U& u)
      requires requires {
        { t < u } -> boolean-testable;
        { u < t } -> boolean-testable;
      }
    {
      if constexpr (three_way_comparable_with<T, U>) {
        return t <=> u;
      } else {
        if (t < u) return weak_ordering::less;
        if (u < t) return weak_ordering::greater;
        return weak_ordering::equivalent;
      }
    };

It's pretty straightforward: if <=> is available, we really want to use <=>. But if <=> isn't available, we fall back to what we had to do in C++17 and use <.
And this has the behavior you want.
Except when... it doesn't.
Let's look back at your type:
struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;

#ifndef DROP_CAST_OP
    constexpr operator bool() const { return x || y; }
#endif

#ifdef USE_SPACESHIP
    constexpr auto operator<=>(const Foo&) const noexcept = default;
#else
    friend constexpr bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) noexcept
    {
        return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
    }
#endif
};

We can go through the various behavior. I'm assuming here that we always provide exactly one of < or <=>:



standard
provide operator bool
which ordering
what happens




c++17
no
<
compares with <


c++17
yes
<
compares with <


c++20
no
<
compares with <


c++20
yes (implicit)
<
compares the result of conversion to bool (see below)


c++20
yes (explicit)
<
compares with <


c++20
no
<=>
compares with <=>


c++20
yes (implicit)
<=>
compares with <=>


c++20
yes (explicit)
<=>
compares with <=>



Keep in mind, the rule is: if <=> works, use <=>, otherwise fall back to <. However, we don't have a mechanism in the language to check how <=> works.
When you provide a <=> to compare the Foos, then <=> exists and is viable and is the best option, so it's unsurprising that it is used.
When you provide a < to compare the Foos, that doesn't in of itself necessarily mean that <=> isn't viable. When you provide an implicit conversion to bool, then f1 <=> f2 is still viable - it evaluates as (bool)f1 <=> (bool)f2 because the builtin candidates are available. This isn't specific to bool - any builtin type (like int or char const*) or other type for which ADL can find a candidate would lead to the same behavior. So according to the language, comparing two Foos with <=> works just fine - so that's the mechanism that we prefer in the library. It's just that in this specific case, it gives surprising behavior, since you probably preferred the explicit < over the implicit <=> by way of the implicit bool conversion.
That's why marking the conversion operator explicit fixes the problem - the builtin operator<=>(bool, bool) is no longer a viable candidate, so there is no viable way to invoke <=> on two Foos. Hence the library falls back to using <.
Note that this isn't even a new problem. If Foo had provided an implicit conversion to bool, but neither an operator< nor a operator<=>, even in C++17 the variant comparison would still work: by way of the implicit conversion to bool. Because evaluating t < u would be a valid expression by way of that conversion. The only novel thing here is that because of the prioritization of <=>, even providing an < doesn't ensure that the library uses the comparison operator that you wrote.

This is an issue that keeps coming up, because people write types that have explicit comparison operators (via <) but also provide an implicit conversion function to a type that has a builtin <=>. Any library mechanism that detects the presence of <=> will give a false positive here, and the only solution is either to provide an explicit <=> yourself or make the conversion function explicit instead of implicit.
If we had a language mechanism to figure out what specifically t <=> u invoked (and there is one proposed in P2825), then we could add additionally validation that we only select <=> if t <=> u and t < u are both viable and invoke the same kind of thing (i.e. that they both invoke the same operator<=> or if the latter invokes a function named operator< that both functions take the same parameter types). But until that happens, be careful with implicit conversion functions in the presence of <=>.

But variant's operator< is viable for varA < varB and it is specified to compare the elements with <, not with <=>. There is no constraint on it using synth-three-way. OP specifies a < overload with exact match in the arguments for Foo, so it should be preferred over the rewritten candidate when checking Foo's with <. Indeed, when calling operator<(varA, varB) explicitly, the static assertion passes. It won't work when selecting operator<=>(varA, varB), but I don't see why the rewritten candidate would be preferred for the expression varA < varB.

@user17732522 It doesn't matter that variant's operator< is viable, variant's operator<=> is also viable and a better candidate and thus preferred.

Ah, I see now. It is because operator<=> is constrained with the three-way comparison concept and then it becomes more specialized in partial ordering of templates than the operator< candidate which has no constraints. Being more specialized in partial ordering of templates has priority over whether or not the candidate is a rewritten one.

@user17732522 Yes, that's exactly why I specified it this way - otherwise <=> would just never be called. We need <=> to be preferred to < if it's viable.

@Barry Thanks for the detailed explanation. This was a real head scratcher.
